# INSERT INTO Across Two Connections Strings

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I know you can use Query across MSSQL with linked server for queries but would Is it possible in an ASP application having say

```
ConectionStringA: \\Server1 Catalog="DB1"
ConectionStringB: \\Server2 Catalog="DB2"
```

Assuming the two databases have same schema to do a

```
INSERT INTO Server1.DB1.dbo.TableA SELECT * FROM Server2.DB2.dbo.TableA 
WHERE Pandas = 'ALilCreepy'
```

????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a single query (unless you can use Linked Servers).  You would need to create two separate queries using two separate connections.

You would run the first to get the records and run the second to insert them.